# Find distribution for a dataset $\mathbf{x} = \{x_1, x_2, ... x_N\} \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: distributions, modeling

Assume I have a dataset of $N$ observations $ \mathbf{x} =\{x_1, x_2, ... x_N\}$ where $\{x_i \in \mathbb{R} | 0 \leq x_i \leq 1\}$ and I want to find out how they are distributed.

Is it possible to do it e.g. with a combination of gaussian distributions and normalizing the result like this:

$f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \mathcal{N}(x_i,\mu)$ , where $\mu$ is considered to be "*very*" small for each $x_i$.

or is this wrong and/or there are better methods I could/should consider?

Comment: Have you considered [kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)?

Comment: Indeed, it sounds exactly like kernel density estimation with a Gaussian kernel. It's a standard thing to do. Many packages do can do this with built in functionality. e.g. in R, `density(x,bw=mu)` will estimate just such a function on data in `x` using a specified value for $\mu$ (I'm assuming $\mu$ is a scale parameter in your parameterization). It can also find a suitable bandwidth - your $\mu$ - on its own, using any of a variety of functions.

Comment: The tags `kernel-density-estimate`, `kde` and `kernel` all seem to have been used for this topic (though the last one has multiple things it refers to). You might try searches using each of those tags by themselves, which should turn up a number of informative posts.

Comment: Thank you guys! I'm going to have a look at your suggestions! @Sameer this really looks like somthing I've been looking for, thank you :)